# How to clone/copy a database in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

How do I clone a database in Azure Cosmos DB to a `mongod` running on localhost:27001?

I've tried the following, but I can't get it working:

```
db.cloneDatabase("mycosmosdb:mypassword@username.documents.azure.com:10255/MyDatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb")
```

This returns the following when running the command from my local machine where `mongod` is running :

```
{
    "clonedColls" : [ ],
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "connect failed to replica set mycosmosdb:mypassword@username.documents.azure.com:10255/Mydatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb:27017",
    "code" : 6,
    "codeName" : "HostUnreachable"
}
```

Trying this variant also fails:

```
db.copyDatabase("NameOfAzureDB", "NameOfLocalDB", "username.documents.azure.com:10255", "username", "password")

{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "couldn't connect to server username.documents.azure.com:27017, connection attempt failed"
}
```

Comment: Note that MongoDB and Cosmos DB are products of two different companies and not necessarily compatible with each other. Cosmos DB provides a API that resembles MongoDB's, but the implementations are entirely different and the same query could have different results between the two.

Answer (score 0):

cloneDatabase is not supported on Cosmos DB as clone command that it wraps around is not flexible enough to allow SSL connection and the name of the replica set. It only accepts the hostname and port number and nothing else, so the connection string used in the question is not supported (and there's no such moniker as "mycosmosdb" either).