# Azure Cosmos DB - Gremlin API to clone existing collection into another collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have created a gremlin api database in Azure Cosmos DB and have data in one collection.

However, I want to know if there is a way to clone the data into another collection in another database.

I want to copy graph data from Dev environment to stage and prod environments.

Comment: I slightly reworded your question to make it easier to read. But please note: you should further improve it yourself. Asking for libraries/tools is off topic here, and the last paragraph alone seems "too broad", too. So: try to restrict your question to more specific aspects, and avoid asking for libraries/tools.

Comment: sure thanks @GhostCat for valuable suggestion

Comment: @rameshs check the answer

Comment: @Sajeetharan where is your answer for this question?

Comment: @Venky https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155167/how-to-clone-copy-a-database-in-azure-cosmos-db/55926196#55926196

Comment: Thanks. Does your solution work for cosmos graph data as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing tools for cosmos SQL API(earlier known as documentdb), cosmosdb allows you to query graph via sql API as well

Something like "select * from c" can fetch you the json representation of how cosmosdb stores your graph data.

The simplest approach would be using [cosmosdb migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data):

1. Set input source as Cosmos SQL API/Documentdb, and use your dev endpoint with the following query `select * from c`
2. Set output type as json and export your data
3. Now use the downloaded json as input source and set your prod graph db as your output(choose documentdb/cosmos SQL API as output type) and run it.

This should push your dev graph data to prod.

You can also use other Azure tools such as data factory, which work with documentdb

Answer (score 0):

Just used this CosmicClone to clone a cosmos db graph database form one account to another https://github.com/microsoft/CosmicClone. Cloned 500k records in 20mins. Looks like it would work with a DB to clone a collection.